# Receving syntax error - MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: sql

```
<field value_field="title" name="catids" default="value"  type="sql" id="categoryid"
       label="Category" description="COM_DOCUMENTS_FIELD_CATEGORY_DESC"
       class="inputbox" query="SELECT id AS value, title AS title FROM #__categories where extension='com_documents'"  multiple="true"
/>
```

Here it is my query. When I excecute this it shows Save failed with the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Looks like you forgot to paste in your query.

Comment: Query seems to be syntactically correct, have you tried running the query alone in your DBMS ?

Comment: <field value_field="title" name="catids" default="value"  type="sql" id="categoryid"
   label="JCATEGORY2" description="COM_DOCUMENTS_FIELD_CATEGORY_DESC"
   class="inputbox" query="SELECT id AS value, title AS title FROM #__categories where extension='com_documents'"  multiple="true"
  />